# Methods for locking SVN tags

Tags: svn, tags, locking

I was wanting to lock down specific tags in an `SVN` repository as soon as they are sent to testing. It seems the `svn lock` command only works on individual files, so this is insufficient as even recursively locking files in the dir would leave the dir roots open for file commits. Using the `SVN` access file also isn't appropriate since the tag names will by dynamic and I will have a mixture of accessible and inaccessible tags within the same tags/ dir; I need to specify an individual tag which I may not know the name of before hand. I also am not able to simply change my strategy at this stage and branch when I wish to lock down a code base; it needs to be a lock on a tag.

There didn't seem to be a lot of support for locking a specific tag/directory in `SVN`; what are the standard methods for achieving these kinds of locks?

Comment: After reading your question for several times, I still don't quite get your purpose of "locking" the tag. To make sure that no one can change the content in tag? or to make sure no one can remove the tag?

Comment: @AdrianShum Well both. Once the tag is sent to testing, no one should be able to add to it or change it in anyway beyond that point, because if the testing is successful, it is released to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- RO for everybody, using Path-based auth, seems as most logical way
- If you don't want it - use pre-commit hook, which reject commit if a hook finds at least one file from transaction in protected tag. Hook will be something like `svnlook changed | grep PATH`

Comment: I can't know in advance what the names of the tags that I want locked will be though, in regards to path based auth. Also, users will have access to the tags dir so even if there was a usr/pass set on a tag, they could just check it out as the user who has access to tags.

Comment: @Aaron - you **must to know** name anyway for path-based ACL or for hook. RO tag **is** locked

Comment: Just add a bit on the way I used to do before:  You don't need to know the names of tag to make it "locked".  I was setting the whole `branches` and `tags` directory as readonly, and only allow special "release" accounts to have write access to it, so tagging are done only by those special release accounts.  This is reasonable as these directory is not for normal people to touch, and permission for specific release branch/ tag should be explicitly released.

Comment: @AdrianShum - RO branches?! Terrible, they are (by nature) RW (with limitations, such as ACLs, but...)!!!

Comment: @LazyBadger It depends on your use.  For my previous job, we want to enforce developers develops on trunk, and do cherry picking to Release branches, so branches by default is only writable by some specific users that performs cherry-picking.  Of course, if you are talking about feature branches, of course that is, by nature, RW

Comment: @AdrianShum - yes, I talk about feature-branches, or, more precisely, about active using branches in development. Trunk-only development in SVN is **nightmare**, even for small teams

Comment: @LazyBadger Agree.  So just to make my point clear: I am talking about release branch, not feature branch  :)